# Targeting .NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-standard

I just create a simple ClassLibrary project with VS2017 preview 2.1. 
I create using .NET Core project template. When I check in project details, I see it targets .NET standard 2.0. How I may target .NET Core 2.0 (that implement a larger number of API according to a test made with API-Port tool)

Comment: I don't think so. Just tried several time using VS2017 15.3/2.1 and in project properties you cannot select .NET Core. It might be a limitation of this release or maybe you need to use CLI to target directly .NET Core 2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is gone with VS2017 15.3.0 Preview 3!

Answer (score 7):

Update: The templates have been fixed in a recent update to VS 2017 15.3 Preview.

This really looks like an issue with the templates, I also created a project from the "Class Library (.NET Core)" template and it targeted .NET Standard 2.0.

However, this can easily be fixed by editing the csproj file manually from

```
<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
```

to

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
```

This project type allows editing the csproj file while the project is loaded by right-clicking on the project and selecting "Edit {project}.csproj".

Answer (score 2):

It looks you may create a .NET Core app with VS2017 targeting .NET Core 2.0, but as soon you create a .NET Core project library, it targets .NET standard, it might be a limitation of this preview of VS2017.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Visual Studio 2017: Community.

I installed the SDK found here: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/dotnet-sdk-2.1.3-windows-x64-installer

You should be able to see the NET Core 2.0 as the target framework when creating your project.